# What does -n do in echo -n mongouser | base64?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes, devops

> echo -n mongouser | base64

Because when I remove -n from the above command, it gives different value than the previous one. Can somebody explain?

Comment: Did you try looking for an `echo` man page? (Actually `echo` is commonly also a shell built-in, but both will have very similar behaviors.)

Answer (score 1):

when you removed `-n` it adds the trailing newline character so the encoded value by `base64` is different.

```
-n    Do not print the trailing newline character.
```

https://man.openbsd.org/echo.1

Comment: Please abstain from answering low-effort questions, especially when they are off-topic _and_ duplicates.